# Attempting to do an Axios call in OnModuleInit

Tags: nestjs

I'm tinkering with NestJs and I'm attempting to do a call for some data in an onModuleInit() the idea is that I would like to get the data before my component completely mounts.  My attempt is:

```
   @Injectable()
    export class CategoriesService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
      onModuleInit() {
        console.log(this.httpService.get('https://api.github.com/users/januaaA'));
      }
    ...
```

When I run this I get the following:

```
the module has been initialized.
Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
```

Am I going in the right direction with this? How would I do the axios call before the project loads and then use the response data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest's `HttpService` is an Observable wrapper around Axios. To make a call in an `async` fashion you need something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  async onModuleInit() {
    console.log(await lastValueFrom(this.httpService.get('https://api.github.com/users/januaaA')));
  }
  ...
}
```

This will now make the RxJS observable fire and use the last (and in this case only) emitted value. `lastValueFrom` is imported from `rxjs`

Comment: or you could use another package instead of `@nestjs/axios`: [`nestjs-http-promise`](https://github.com/benhason1/nestjs-http-promise) if you don't want to use observables